# On changing jar path Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException appears

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I exported executable jar and while exporting ,I provide path D:/ in eclipse.
When i execute jar from same path,it works fine but when I placed the same jar in a folder in same directory and execute it shows "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException".
Note-jar was exported using package required libraries option.

Comment: add jars from java build path-> libraries -> add external jars

Comment: Its not duplicate,Please read problem statement.